# Google Ad mob ad not displayed in play store build

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I have developed a flutter application and integrated google admob

For this I have used [firebase_admob](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_admob) plugin to integrate google ads in application

1. Ads displayed in debug mode - Test ads
2. When I install app.apk from output folder in device live ads are displayed
3. But when I download application from play store the ads are not displayed

Comment: It usually takes some time to show ads on Play-store uploaded APK.

Comment: It's been a 20 days till now

Comment: Any solution for this issue?